# Главная функция не видит значение return импортируемого модуля

Tags: python-3.x, return

Я две недели назад начал изучать Python.

Хочу, чтобы main вызывал нужные модули. Модули после завершения своей работы должны возвращать результат main функции. После этого главная функция должна быть в состоянии работать дальше с полученными значениями.
К сожалению, я не понимаю, как возможно передать результат работы из нижнего модуля наверх.

```
#main.py
import addModul
import multiplicationModul
a = eval (input ('задайте значение первой переменной '))
b = eval (input ('задайте значение второй переменной '))
addModul.addModul (a, b)
multiplicationModul.multiplicationModul(a, b)
```

Модули после завершения своей работы должны возвращать результат main функции. После этого главная функция должна быть в состоянии работать дальше с полученными значениями.

```
def addModul  (a=0, b=0):
        summe = a + b
        print ('a + b =', summe)
        return summe


def multiplicationModul (a, b):
    multipl = a * b
    print ('a * b =', multipl)
    return multipl
```

Я понимаю, что: (1) после выполнения return работа функции сразу останавливается (2) return возвращает не имя переменной, а её значение.

Я не понимаю, как вернуть значение вызванного модуля на верхний уровень?

Объясните пожалуйста, что я делаю неправильно.

Comment: `_add = addModul.addModul (a, b)`; `_multiplication =   multiplicationModul.multiplicationModul(a, b)`; `print(_add,  _multiplication)`

Comment: Большое спасибо S. Nick !!!
Работает :0)